# Find string in HTML file and return adjacent value using Python

Tags: python, html, file

I have an HTML file which has a bunch of fields, among which a specific string appears followed by a value within parenthesis. For example: RECORD_DURATION (0:00:15). The string RECORD_DURATION will occur multiple times throughout the HTML file. I want to write a script which will search for the RECORD_DURATION string and return the value within the parenthesis next to the string. So I'm anticipating my output to look something like this:

> > 0:00:15

Or if there are multiple durations (which is almost always the case), then return a list containing those values

> > [0:00:15, 0:00:08, 0:00:11]

The code I have so far only attempts to read the entire file and return a line which has the string in it:

```
with open("filename.html", 'r') as searchfile:
     for line in searchfile:
          if 'RECORD_DURATION' in line:
               print line
```

However, the entire file is in a line so it ends up returning everything. Is there a way to do this cleverly in Python?

Comment: investigate beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest is the following: `before, after = line.split('RECORD_DURATION',1)`

This is gonna get unwieldy quickly tho, so either use look at the "re" module, or better, the "beautifulsoup" module.

Comment: Btw, HTML + regex = tears.